# GameKit (GKSession) : Is there a priority order when GKSession decides to use Wifi or Bluetooth (if both are available)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xamarin.ios, bluetooth, gamekit

If I have two iOS devices, both on same WiFi network and both with Bluetooth turned on, and I use GameKit (specifically GKSession) to manually setup a communications channel between them (without using GKPeerPickerController), I cant tell if it is using WiFi or Bluetooth.

Does iOS prioritise one over the other? I'm hoping that it uses Wifi before Bluetooth, but id like to be sure.

If WiFi is available and bluetooth isn't, it uses Wifi, if Bluetooth is available and Wifi isn't, it uses Bluetooth. Im wondering how they're talking if both bluetooth and WiFi are available, which does GameKit choose over the other?

The only way I can see to find this out is by running a packet sniffer on my WiFi and running several tests across different devices. Kinda hoping someone can save me that effort!

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GameKit/Reference/GKPeerPickerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) if you use a `GKPeerPickerController` to create your `GKSession` you will be able to select bluetooth or wifi connectivity (see GKPeerPickerConnectionType).

> I'm hoping that it uses Wifi before Bluetooth, but id like to be sure.

It [seems](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1) an internet connections requires a bit of user code (but not bluetooth) so I would *guess* it defaults to bluetooth to avoid making this requirement mandatory.

Comment: Sorry, meant to clarify that im not using the GKPeerPickerController. Currently I have two devices connecting to each other using a GKSession, if I turn off wifi on both of them, they still connect (via bluetooth i assume). If I turn off bluetooth on both of them, they still connect (via wifi i assume). Im just wondering how they are connecting when both bluetooth and wifi are available to them?

The GKPeerPickerController is not suitable for what I need to do.

Comment: The second link makes me think it's bluetooth - but you can use Wireshark to see the wireless traffic (from another computer) and determine if Wifi is being used (or not).